# when piping command, is nice applied to all chain?

Tags: bash, pipe, nice

Consider the following case

```
nice -10 mysqldump -u crontab -p'readonly' --databases "$1" | gzip > $hour_folder"/"$1"_h"$hour".sql.gz"
```

I aask you if `nice` is applied only to `mysqldumnp` or is applied to `gzip`, too?

Comment: No. It shouldn't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, `nice` (as opposed to the `!` or `time` shell keywords for instance¹) is a standalone command, so it could not apply to other commands that are piped to it or that it is piped to.

The change of niceness is only applied to the process that `nice` is executed in that will later execute the command passed as arguments (and all the processes that that command may itself spawn as niceness is inherited upon fork).

If you want to increase the niceness of both commands, you'd need two separate calls to `nice`:

```
nice cmd1 | nice cmd2
```

Or have `nice` start a shell that starts the pipeline:

```
nice sh -c 'cmd1 | cmd2'
```

Or you could increase the niceness of the current shell or subshell process with `renice` prior to starting the pipeline (beware some `renice`  implementations *set* the niceness while others *increase* it by the specified amount).

With `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/system
(renice 10 $sysparam[pid]; cmd1 | cmd2)
```

With `bash`:

```
(renice 10 "$BASHPID"; cmd1 | cmd2)
```

In `zsh`, commands started asynchronously have their niceness increased by 5 (unless the `bgnice` option is disabled), so you could also do:

```
(cmd1 | cmd2 &) &
```

To increase the niceness of both commands by 10.

```
$ ps -o nice,args | cat
 NI COMMAND
  0 /bin/zsh
  0 ps -o nice,args
  0 cat
$ nice ps -o nice,args | cat
 NI COMMAND
  0 /bin/zsh
 10 ps -o nice,args
  0 cat
$ nice ps -o nice,args | nice cat
 NI COMMAND
  0 /bin/zsh
 10 ps -o nice,args
 10 cat
$ ps -o nice,args | cat &
 NI COMMAND
  0 /bin/zsh
  5 ps -o nice,args
  5 cat
$ (ps -o nice,args | cat &) &
 NI COMMAND
  0 /bin/zsh
 10 ps -o nice,args
 10 cat
```

Also beware that in `nice mysqldump...`, a lot of the CPU time used by that operation will be spent by the `mysqld` process handling the requests by `mysqldump`, and `nice` only sets the niceness of the process that is executing `mysqldump`,  that has no effect on the niceness of the MySQL server processes themselves.

---

<sup>`!` and `time` in `bash` and some other Korn-like shells are keywords in the shell language, not commands. They apply to the following pipeline. Beware though that if there's a `-p` word following `time` or if `time` is   quoted in any way, then the `time` standalone command is run instead and therefore only applies to the command passed as its arguments.</sup>

Comment: The second format is not correct! Maybe you were meaning `nice bash -c 'cmd1 | cmd2'`

Comment: @FedonKadifeli, yes sorry. Fixed now (using `sh` instead of `bash`)